# How to join table with table_range function in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT
  *
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(dataset.tableA, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1,'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'day')) AS org_table
JOIN (
  SELECT
    name,
    id
  FROM
    dataset.tableB) AS new_table
ON
   org_table.id = new_table.id
```

BigQuery don't allow me to give alias for TABLE_DATE_RANGE(), how to do this join ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(dataset.tableA, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1,'day'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'day'))
) AS org_table
JOIN (
  SELECT
    name,
    id
  FROM
    dataset.tableB) AS new_table
ON
   org_table.id = new_table.id
```